# save data of the app, and not loose them if i update the app

Tags: objective-c, save

If I have local data of an app, suppose a local highscore where I store all the scores of the game.
If I release an update of the app, I lose all data.
I save data with this method:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"defaultStage.dat"];

char cstr[512]={0};
[filename getCString:cstr maxLength:512 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

defaultStage=1;
FILE *pFile=fopen(cstr, "wb");
// and save with fprintf
```

There is a way that save the data "permanently" not to lose when I reinstall, or update the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving to the Documents directory shouldn't loose your data when you update, strange. Does it really? As for deleting and reinstalling the app, there's no way to save the data locally on the phone (ie outside your app's sandbox which gets deleted when the app is deleted). You would need to use iCloud or a remote web server.

For saving a high score I would recommend using NSUserDefaults which also wouldn't get deleted when you update your app.

edit : I assume you talk about iOS, not OS X

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to save data under iOS/Mac OS X. You can start by taking a look at [Core data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Check how much data you want to save, and see which one fits your need.

Comment: so instead of NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
i could use: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSUserDefaults, NSUserDomainMask, YES);?